# Benchmark Test Software Running on Windows and Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, benchmarking

Just wondering if there is any benchmark software that I can download that will run on both Windows (preferable Windows 7) and Linux (Ubuntu 9.10)?  I have a brand new system and I'd like to run some standardized benchmarks with Ubuntu and also with Windows 7.  The Passmark Performance test only runs under Windows.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends greatly of what your metric is.  "Back then when" we worried more about integer vs floating-point performance the [dhrystone test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhrystone) was popular.  It will test the 'ecompiler + os' combination, but say nothing about graphics, or disk, or other aspects.

Wikipedia also has number of other [open source benchmarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_%28computing%29#Open_source_benchmarks) listed you could try.

Answer (score 1):

[Geekbench](http://www.primatelabs.ca/geekbench/) runs under both Windows and Linux (in addition to Mac OS X and Solaris).